# Using Python to scrape linkedin connections but only some show up- Selenium and BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup

So the title says it all. I am trying to scrape the connections based upon a search term I supply. Once the page renders, all of the connections aren't in the html as if they are hidden until I scroll down to see them. Is there a way to use Selenium to show all of the connections at once? I have no code to post since this is only a question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use selenium to scroll down the page, loading the data you intend to grab.

The code bellow will scroll to the bottom of the page:

```
...
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
...
```

I've had an use case where I had to hit the bottom of the page consecutive times to load the content and get all the data I needed, in which I used the mentioned approach.

Hope this helps...